# @DateTimeFormat in Spring produces off-by-one day error

Tags: spring, datetime, spring-mvc, format

I am currently using @DateTimeFormat in a domain object as follows:

```
@DateTimeFormat(pattern = "MM/dd/yyyy")
private Date startDate = new Date();
```

In a Spring MVC Controller, I am posting today's date: 10/19/2011 using the jQuery UI Date picker, and I confirm that this is being sent as an HTTP Post parameter using firebug as follows:

```
startDate=10%2F19%2F2011
```

Unfortunately, once it gets to Spring on the server, it stores the date as 10/18/2011 - there is an off-by-one day error.

There is nothing in my code that even remotely touches the date - there is no calculations or anything going on with regards to this date.

Is there something about @DateTimeFormat that I should be aware of?

Could something in Hibernate be responsible for changing the date too?

I'm also looking at the my database for this application. I am storing another date, called `creationDate` which is an actual timestamp and differs from user input. In most cases, the dates are the same but the client wanted the ability to set it differently so that is what `startDate` is for.

```
Start Date              Creation Date (actual timestamp, not user input)
2011-04-17 19:00:00     2011-04-17 21:32:27
2011-04-18 19:00:00     2011-04-18 21:14:01
2011-04-20 19:00:00     2011-04-20 23:06:47
2011-04-26 19:00:00     2011-04-26 23:24:34
2011-04-28 19:00:00     2011-04-28 20:07:06
2011-05-01 19:00:00     2011-05-02 13:35:37
2011-06-21 19:00:00     2011-06-22 15:06:36
2011-07-28 19:00:00     2011-07-29 15:32:35
2011-09-03 19:00:00     2011-09-04 13:11:45
2011-10-11 19:00:00     2011-10-12 11:45:14
2011-10-11 19:00:00     2011-10-12 11:49:55
2011-10-18 19:00:00     2011-10-19 02:20:43
```

At first it seems like it was a bug started in May, but then I realized that the date is correct if it was over 19:00:00, and it's off-by-one if it's under 19:00:00.

I hate Java :(

The problem seems to occur when Spring creates a date given `10/19/2011` - it seems to translate that user input and formats it to `2011-10-18 19:00:00`.

What is the simplest solution?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems very likely to me that this is *actually* a matter of time zones. A `Date` object represents an *instant* in time - I suspect if you look at the exact value that you've got (e.g. in UTC, to keep things clear) you'll get a better idea of what's going on. Chances are that where you're seeing "10/18/2011" you're interpreting it in a different time zone.

If Spring supports converting to [Joda Time](http://joda-time.sf.net) types I'd suggest using that instead - then you can use `LocalDate` which really *does* mean a date instead of an instant in time.

Comment: Yeah, you could be right. I don't use JodaTime because it often creates all sorts of dependency problems with Hibernate. I don't need to do any fancy calculations, so I've been avoiding to keep my dependencies simpler. How can I fix this without using joda time? Just set the time to always be over 19:00:00?

Comment: @egervari: It's hard to suggest a fix without really knowing what the problem is. You've edited your post to show "start date" but without showing how you got that. It *could* be that by using UTC everywhere, you solve all your problems, for example.

Comment: The start date is not a calculation. It is user-input. The system sets the current date to the default, and that is the date that ended up getting stored. Everything about this part of the application is trivial - the controller, the service layer, and the dao. I am using standard Hibernate to store it, and I not even setting the type - so it is basically hibernate's default date type too. Everything is the default - that's what I'm saying. It's super trivial. I hope I don't have to convert everything to Joda Time. While I recognize that is better, I don't want to invest that kind of time.

Comment: Also, my fix that I edited does not work on the server... so I'd rather not use it. What is the simplest fix I can do to get Spring to create a date that doesn't produce this off-by-one error? The obvious problem is inside of Spring - not my code. @DateTimeFormat seems to be the culprit.

Comment: @egervari: No, there *is* a calculation involved - two, actually. You've parsed the user input into a Date, and then when diagnosing this you've *formatted* the value from a Date to a string. Both of those calculations involve time zones - the first sounds like it's out of your control, but you haven't shown what you've done for the second. It's not at all clear to me that Spring *is* doing anything wrong. It's quite possible that it's giving you midnight UTC, and you just happen to be formatting it using the local time zone inappropriately.

Comment: Well, how can I change the formatting code? I am telling spring using the annotation: `@DateTimeFormat(pattern = "MM/dd/yyyy")`. There is no other part of the application that handles this. What can I do to give it the proper timezone? I don't think this is a web formatting error (the second part) because you can obviously see from my database values that creating a new date (`creationDate` in my table) does not suffer from this problem. Only the @DateTimeFormat (the `startDate`) has this problem.

Comment: @egervari: The `@DateTimeFormat` is for *parsing*, surely. Write code to log the `startDate` variable using a `SimpleDateFormat` with the time zone set to UTC.

Comment: @DateTimeFormat is using SimpleDateFormat under the covers. How can I tell it to use the UTC timezone?

Comment: @egervari: I don't know, but the most important thing to do first is to diagnose *exactly* what the parsed value is. Put in the logging that I suggested, at which point we'll have a better idea of what's going on.

Comment: (According to the [docs](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/format/annotation/DateTimeFormat.html), `@DateTimeFormat` can be applied to Joda Time fields, btw.)

Comment: Well, this is going to be hard to give accurate info about what's going on since the server and local machine differ. When I use `SimpleTimeFormat` directly, the result is `Wed Oct 19 00:00:00 EDT 2011`. I will get back to you and tell you what happens when I log this on the server though.

Comment: @egervari: You've clearly still not set the time zone to UTC on your SimpleDateFormat though, for logging. That's what I'm trying to get at. Heck, just logging `startDate.getTime()` would be a start...

Comment: I don't know how to set the timezone. The documentation on how to set utc is so cryptic I am lost. The date api is so non-sensical and unintuitive that I don't know how to use it. I don't program every day anymore. Locally, after I parse the date using SimpleDateFormat, the method getTime() returns 1318996800000

Comment: @egervari: You call `dateFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"))`. I agree that the java.util.Date/Calendar APIs are cryptic, which is why I recommended Joda Time. When you say "Locally, after I parse the date" - do you mean you're doing that *yourself* in code, or using `@DateTimeFormat`? My suggestion was to log the time *which had been parsed by Spring*.

Comment: After using your code to set the timezone, I get `Tue Oct 18 20:00:00 EDT 2011` for the date. The `getTime()` method returns `1318982400000`. I know JodaTime would solve this... it would just cause to have to convert dozens of domain objects that also probably share this problem and also have to restructure Hibernate configuration to use them that it would probably be many hours of work. I'm not even getting paid to do this, so I was hoping for a 1-line wonder to solve the problem.

Comment: Well, I set the timezone on the server to the same as my development machine, so now at least the server takes "01/19/2011" and converts it to `2011-10-18 20:00:00`. How can I stop @SimpleDateFormat from using the UTC like this? I just don't want it to do this.

Comment: Actually, now I'm convinced that the Windows and Linux versions of the JDK are different. The default timezone for this date using SimpleDateFormat on windows is 10/19/2011 00:00:00, but it is 10/18/2011 20:00:00 on Linux. I'm guessing I've been running into a cross-platform issue the whole time. Sigh. Should I just set the timezone on the server to be 00:00:00? Will that work you think?

Comment: @egervari: You shouldn't need to set the time zone on the server at all - you should set the time zone when parsing and formatting. I would *expect* the Spring annotation to do this for you automatically, but you've been very unclear about what results you're giving - for example, it sounds like you're just using `Date.toString()` to determine the result, and that *always* uses the default time zone. I wanted you to take the Date that's been *parsed* by the spring annotation, but then you *format* that using SimpleDateFormat set to UTC. That result *should not* include "EDT" anywhere.

Comment: Are you serious that it always uses the default time zone, even if the timezone is set using the formatter? My god is this api garbage. Sorry, I didn't know that. that's not intuitive to me at all. Now it's more clear what you want me to do. On my local machine, when I log this `DateFormat.format(startDate)` using the UTC timezone, I get `10/19/2011`. I'd have to upload this to the server to tell you what the server outputs. This will take about 15 minutes.

Comment: @egervari: Change the format to show the *whole* date and time, not just the date part. Otherwise we can't see what's coming out. And yes, Date *just represents an instant in time*. That's somewhat reasonable, although the name's not great. It doesn't have any concept of the time zone. The time zone is only used to work out what instant is associated with the parsed local time.

Comment: The local machine says 2011.10.19 AD at 04:00:00 UTC. To get this on the server, I'll have to upload it.

Comment: Okay, on the server it outputs: `2011.10.19 AD at 00:00:00 UTC` The time is 7:34 am eastern when I did this. It would appear that it's a different result than my local system.

Comment: I want to be clear too... I don't want to format this date on the view to the correct date, but not have it stored like the other dates in the database. The last thing I want is for some date objects to have to be converted with a timezone, but others not to be this way. This would be crazy confusing long-term... to know which dates you need to format and which dates you need to leave alone. For example, the creation date that is stored in the database is CORRECT - I don't want to compensate for a timezone for this date when I output it. The start date is clearly wrong though. So confusing.

Comment: @egervari: It's still not clear where you got the value from though - is that the result of the spring annotation parsing, or you *parsing* with SimpleDateFormat yourself? If you could show the complete code you're using to get this log out, it would help. I would *recommend* storing UTC in the database, by the way.

Comment: Obviously it's being parsed through the annotation. This is how you do it with spring now. As for UTC... I would have to convert all the dates in the entire database to achieve this. Wow, that would be a lot of work. There is over 50 database tables and so many dates :( It seems like this problem is not going to be easy to solve regardless of what I do. I guess using Joda time and the crappy Joda-Hibernate project is the way to go. Or I have to write my own bridge between Joda Time and Hibernate. Pitty. Thanks for all the diagnostics help though.

Comment: @egervari: It wasn't obvious that you were parsing it through the annotation - I thought at one point that you were *parsing* a string with a `SimpleDateFormat` that you'd created and then printing the result with `Date.toString` for example. If your database *isn't* using UTC for each date/time value, then what *is* it using? At the very least you should consider what the appropriate information is for each field in your system... is it actually recording an instant in time, or a local date/time in a particular time zone, or just a date. Use the right type for each place.

Comment: It's just a date in this case, although in most cases, it is date/time. There just wasn't any need to consider time zones for this application - and probably never will. The only reason I have it in this case is because Java had no way to represent a date without a time and a timezone. If anything, I see this problem as Java's fault more than anything. It is much difficult to set the timezone for every single date. That gets rid of the nice and simple `new Date()` initializers for timestamps. I just wish the designers of these apis thought about the use-cases of 99% of people rather than 1%.

Comment: And I only say it's obvious, but I guess if you don't use spring 3.0, then maybe it wouldn't be. Nonetheless, @DateTimeFormat is a declarative way to tell spring, "Use this format whenever you need to convert a string to a date in the entire system." As far as I know, you can't even specify the target timezone using this method, so even the Spring engineers screwed this up if what you're saying is true. If you ask me, the whole date api is shit. I have no choice but to go to joda time. I just think it's stupid that I have to spend many hours converting it to fix 1 field on the entire site.

Comment: @egervari: Yes, I'm aware of what Spring does, and it was obvious what you were using in the app itself - what wasn't clear was what you were doing to diagnose the problem. For example, I was suggesting that you use `SimpleDateFormat`, but you were still using `Date.toString`. This is where it's helpful if you provide the code that gives you the output. That would have saved quite a bit of the back and forth.

Comment: Well, I switched to JodaTime and that didn't fix the problem. It turns out that Spring's support for JodaTime is merely a conversion between Date to LocalDate and vice-versa, so Spring is still using the buggy SimpleDateFormat class, which is probably the source of my problems. I have reported the problem to Spring Jira website. Even though this is likely a problem with the Linux version of the JDK (windows is fine), there's no way to configure the JDK via the annotation. In fact, there's no timezone settings on this annotation at all - which is a big limitation. So, bug reported to them.

Comment: @egervari: SimpleDateFormat isn't buggy in this respect - but it can be misused. In particular, if you want a particular time zone you need to set it appropriately. You've been very critical of a number of classes in this comment thread - it's worth making sure you're pointing the finger in the right direction before ascribing blame.

Comment: I am not calling SimpleDateFormat directly though. Spring is. I am using the annotation. There is no timezone options. What I'm saying is this: If this is a problem that basically everyone is going to have, then why not provide options to solve it? Instead, it's a total black box and the annotation is basically useless. All I'm doing is passing a `"10/19/2011"` into a LocalDate, and I expect it to be `LocalDate(10/19/2011)`. This is not hard to ask for. In fact, I would say this is a pretty basic requirement that it is failing to meet. There's also no way to circumvent the problem either.

Comment: Objectively, the problem is two-fold. The core problem is in the JDK - the Linux version of it to be exact. If this is by design and it so happens that it's really the Windows version that is not working to spec (because they give two different outcomes with the same version number), then it is Spring's fault for not providing options to mitigate this problem in their annotation. Either way, the problem isn't with my application code.

Comment: @egervari: I don't think it's at all obvious *where* the problem is yet. You've been busily assigning blame all over the place, but without actually debugging into what's going on, we really can't say what's wrong. *Maybe* Spring isn't setting the right time zone on the `SimpleDateFormat` it's using to parse. *Maybe* there's a bug in the Linux JDK, although that seems less likely. Even though the problem may not be with your application code, you've caused significant confusion by not showing the code you've used to diagnose the problem. (Continued)

Comment: I suggested that you format the `Date` using `SimpleDateFormat` set to UTC, but you appeared to use `Date.toString` instead - leading to confusion. It's always helpful to *show the code you're using to get the results you're posting*. I'm looking for the Spring source now to see whether it *looks* like the bug is there or not... but I really think you're likely to find that the Spring team is more willing to help you if you don't *assume* you know where the problem is.

Comment: I have told you the results using the formatter though. I was using DateFormat.format(date). I gave you the results for this already. I also logically can assume that the problem is due to the JDK on Linux. How do I know this? Because it works on Windows just fine. Also, the problem persists whether I use the JDK `Date` class or the Joda Time `LocalDate` class. This suggests that Spring is using the JDK for both things. Since I get 2 different results on Windows or Linux, it would suggest a bug in the JDK, and not Spring. However, this means Spring must change their code to avoid the jdk bug.

Comment: @egervari: You've given me *various* results, presumably using various different bits of code. If you'd edited the code into the question, alongside the results from that code, it would have been a lot clearer. And no, I don't think you can really conclude it's a JDK bug yet. You may be able to if you write a short but complete console program which demonstrates the problem without involving Spring at all, but I haven't seen any evidence that you've done that yet.

Comment: I've done that, just didn't show it. If you haven't noticed, not being able to press 'enter' to create a new line sort of makes it difficult to paste big sections of code in the responses. Regardless, I've given up on the problem and told Spring about it. If they don't fix it in the next day or so, I'm probably going to pass the timezone information specifically via the HTTP Post parameter, which sounds absolutely asinine, but it will probably work.

Comment: @egervari: Rather than adding it into a comment, you should put it in the question and comment that you've updated it. It logically *belongs* in the question. If you can make that edit now, I'll look at it.

Comment: Also, we can conclusively say 100% of the time that this is a bug. Windows and Linux versions of the JDK give different results here. One of them is wrong.

Comment: @egervari: "We" can't say that yet - you may think you can, but I'm not going to agree to it until I've seen the code. If there's *anything* in your repro which uses system settings (system locale, system time zone etc) then that could easily explain it. When I've seen the code, I'll be able to agree or disagree.

Answer (score 1):

I've found that starting your JVM with your local timezone specified in the arguments solves this issue. For me it was just adding this line to the run configuration:

```
-Duser.timezone="Asia/Dhaka"
```